# pluralize and singularize for spanish language

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, pluralize, singular

sorry for my english...

I have a rails application developed to spain, therefore, all content is in spanish, so, I have a search box to search in a mysql database, all rows are in spanish, I'd like to improve my search to allow to users to search keywords in singular or plural form, for example:

```
keyword: patatas
found: patata

keyword: veces
found: vez

keyword: vez
found: veces

keyword: actividades
found: actividad
```

In english, this could be relatively easy with help of singularize and pluralize methods ...

```
where `searching_field` like '%singularized_keyword%' or `searching_field` like '%pluralized_keyword%'
```

But, for spanish....

Some help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found this great way:
http://www.slideshare.net/crnixon/advanced-internationalization-with-rails

Regards.

Comment: Cheers for finding a solution.  Best to place (at least some of!) the answer on this site, since external links are prone to breaking

Answer (score 9):

You can define your own inflections now.

look in config/initializers/inflections.rb

an example based on your question

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.irregular 'patata', 'patatas'
end
```

Thus

```
"patata".pluralize # => "patatas"
"patatas".singularize #=> "patata"
```

Of course you need to know the list of keywords in advance to use the irregular method in config/inflections.rb. Have a look at the commented out examples in that file. There are other methods that allow one to define rules using regular expressions and you could devise pattern matches to affect inflections for arbitrary keywords that match known patterns.

Answer (score 5):

You have to clear all default inflections in English and create new ones in Spanish.

Add in *config/initializers/inflections.rb*

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.clear :all

  inflect.plural /([^djlnrs])([A-Z]|_|$)/, '\1s\2'
  inflect.plural /([djlnrs])([A-Z]|_|$)/, '\1es\2'
  inflect.plural /(.*)z([A-Z]|_|$)$/i, '\1ces\2'

  inflect.singular /([^djlnrs])s([A-Z]|_|$)/, '\1\2'
  inflect.singular /([djlnrs])es([A-Z]|_|$)/, '\1\2'
  inflect.singular /(.*)ces([A-Z]|_|$)$/i, '\1z\2'
end
```

Answer (score 4):

It seems that it is now possible to use localized inflections now:

```
# config/initializers/inflections.rb
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections(:es) do |inflect|
  inflect.plural /([^djlnrs])([A-Z]|_|$)/, '\1s\2'
  inflect.plural /([djlnrs])([A-Z]|_|$)/, '\1es\2'
  inflect.plural /(.*)z([A-Z]|_|$)$/i, '\1ces\2'

  inflect.singular /([^djlnrs])s([A-Z]|_|$)/, '\1\2'
  inflect.singular /([djlnrs])es([A-Z]|_|$)/, '\1\2'
  inflect.singular /(.*)ces([A-Z]|_|$)$/i, '\1z\2'
end
```

With that (and after restarting the server) you can use:

```
"trebol".pluralize(:es) #=> "treboles"
```

Comment: Note that, acute (agudas) words ending in s, like "crisis" with those rules.